# Installing perl with dynamic loading on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu, perl-module

I'm trying to install Perl on Ubuntu 11.04 and I need it to have dynamic loading option. During ./Configure it asks me location of source file for dynamic loader. I'm not able to find the appropriate one for linux. Using dl_dlopen.xs gives compile-time error about undefined references.

Can anyone help me find the correct Dynamic Loader source file? Or tell me about any alternative way to install Perl with dynamic loading?

Comment: Are you really sure the normal, system-delivered perl doesn't already have it? It'd be weird if it didn't, but I don't have an Ubuntu that old around to check on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The flag for dynamic linking loader was missing. I added -ldl to the list of flags while running ./Configure script and it worked.
The correct dynamic loader for Ubuntu is dl_dlopen.xs itself.